# Cannot send httponly cookie to express server from react js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am working on a `react` app which receives `httponly` cookie from third party website.

I am able to see the cookie in Chrome developer `console`.
I am trying to send this cookie to backend of my app, built in `expressjs`, so that I can read the cookie. I am using `fetch` to send a `GET` request to the app while including the `prop` below:

```sh
Credentials: 'include'
```

In the `express` server, am allowing my front-end inside `CORS` and also
set credentials equal to true.

**Issue**:
In request header of my `express` server, I can't see the `httponly` cookie.

Can anyone guide me how can I send `httponly` and get it inside `express` server?

Answer (score 2):

On client you must enable credentials as well. There is `axios` module to make requests with credentials. Example of usage:

```
import axios from 'axios'

const instance = axios.create({
  withCredentials: true,
  baseURL: API_SERVER
})

instance.get('todos')
```

In other way, you could provide `cookie` with `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://example.com/', true);
xhr.withCredentials = true;
xhr.send(null);
```

[XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials)

Comment: I tried to use axios with withCredentials prop set to true, but I am still not able to get httponly third party cookies inside my backend server(express server). I can only see my app cookies in backend.

Comment: So you are not providing these cookies. Try setting them into browser cookies, or store somewhere else in memory and send these values as the request params.

Comment: Can you please explain how I can set third party cookies in browser cookies.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is allow our Express application to be able to receive requests from the host on which the Fetch API makes the calls in our situation it makes them from https://localhost:8080

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors({
origin: 'http://localhost:8080',
credentials: true
}));
```

The last thing is to create a fetch request via the Fetch API from [https://localhost:8080] to [http://localhost:9090/example]:

```
fetch('http://localhost:9090/example',{
method: ‘GET’,
credentials: 'include'
});
```

And now no matter that we made the request from another host ,we receive the cookies

Comment: This is already done, but I am not able to see httponly cookies. These httponly cookies are from third party domain for example.  (.abc.com)